# Fn key combinations don't work on Asus laptop on windows 8

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, windows-8-preview, asus-laptop, function-keys

Only 5 out of 12 function keys combinations work. The volume manager doesn't work and the disable/enable touch pad which I used A LOT doesn't work and it's killing me.

Does anybody found a solution to this??

Comment: Did you install the Asus utilities?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ASUS has finally released the **ATK Drivers** for Windows 8. All the function keys, including volume up/down, brightness control and wireless switch work perfectly on Windows 8 after installing it. You can download the driver for 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows 8 from here: [ATK Package](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&m=ATKPackage&hashedid=n/a)

Comment: Finally! Thank you for your update! I already installed it and it's working. Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks mate! Somehow I couldn't find that page with Google, so +1 to you!

Answer (score 4):

Been searching around and figured I'd help with this problem a bit. I'm running a G73 and had the same concerns, but with some digging I seem to be fixing this slight nuisance a few keys at a time. So far so good. I've restored my WiFi on/off, Volume mute/up/down, Touchpad on/off, and Keyboard light up/down. In the process of getting the rest.

Asus now has an option in their downloads section for "Drivers for Win8" and "Apps for Win8". When you go to select model just click Notebook and scroll through the options in the series panel till you find the quoted selections. Make sure you select the right drivers for the brand of hardware you got. I'll post again if there's a problem with any of the drivers. Also some of the drivers for the G75 are compatible as well.

Here's a link to the [downloads page](http://www.service.asus.com/#!Downloads/c1wax) from Asus.

Edit: The ATI 5870 Graphics driver from ASUS didn't fix my brightness fn keys. Had to go to ATI's site. Driver from there works perfect. Use the branded Drivers from the graphics manufacturers website if you have something else.

Answer (score 3):

Some people get all their function keys working even without installing any separate drivers for that, some don't. It varies with models.

First option is to download and install **ATK drivers** for you model from the Asus Website : http://www.service.asus.com/#!Downloads/

They have released Windows 8 drivers, software compatibility fixes etc. So select OS accordingly.

If possible, update all the drivers available there.

Below two posts might help you regarding this :

http://www.eightforums.com/hardware-drivers/10464-disabled-fn-keys.html
http://forum.notebookreview.com/asus/643774-asus-n73s-fn-media-keys-dont-work.htmlstrong text

Answer (score 2):

ASUS doesn't have a version of their utilities driver software available for Windows 8 yet (according to their website).

Answer (score 0):

I am using K53SM, and had this exact similar problem. Installing the **latest drivers,** and **updating the bios** did the trick.