# Win8 drivers for Asus U36SD

Tags: windows-8, drivers, asus-laptop

I bought Asus u36sd notebook last year, when Win8 was in preview, and after official release asus responded to my support question that they'll not release win8 drivers. Interestingly, there are win8 drivers for other models in U36S series (u36sg, u36sj).

I tried win8 nevertheless, but there are some annoyances: after returning from sleep it takes 10-30 sec for wifi to start working, on-screen keyboard shortcuts display (for volume or brightness) is working then stops (problem described here: [Windows 8 on ASUS notebook, brightness down does not work](https://superuser.com/questions/552178/windows-8-on-asus-notebook-brightness-down-does-not-work)), etc.
Drivers from other model in series doesn't help, same problems.

Has anybody configured win8 on u36sd? Where did you find device drivers? Any other recommendations?

Comment: Without official driver support from the manufacturer it's going to be difficult to fix those annoyances. A supported OS such as Win7 or Linux might be the best course of action, but perhaps someone has a better idea.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of the problem is BIOS. Some ASUS models are updated to Windows 8, but some are not.
There is a note for the latest BIOS versions, such as "added Windows 8 support".

If you wish to get Windows 8 support on your model, you could try to convince ASUS, or make your own version of BIOS, which I have seen for N53SV model (some person did make by himself).

Comment: make my own version of BIOS? You mean, lock myself in basement for 5 years, figure out how bios are programmed, reverse engineer current bios and do the modifications? Oh, easy!